# UINavigation back bar button

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, backbarbuttonitem

I have a `UITableViewController` as the `root view controller` of a `UINavigationController`.

When the app launches, there is no back bar button on the navigation bar. However, when I click on one of the table view cells, and then click back, a back bar button appears at the top of the original `UITableViewController`.  I don't want this.  How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Since the back button is managed by the UINavigationController, there must be something to go back to. I'm curious what happens when you tap the back button? You must be pushing something else onto the navigation stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On any view controllers that you *don't* want the back button to show, you can add this to the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:NO];
```

Alternatively, you can add this call in `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated:` if you want the change to be animated:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:animated];
```

Answer (score 0):

When your application opens up, the `UITableViewController` doesn't show a `Back` button because **there is nothing to go back to**.  That's the Initial View Controller.

As for the second `UIViewController` that **pushes on top** of the previous `UITableViewController` - if you don't want the `Back` button in that - use a `Modal` transfer and not a `Push` transfer.

Apple's `Navigation Controller` simply functions like that. It works like a stack. One `UIViewController` gets **pushed** on the current one.

However, if you still want a `Navigation Bar` on top of the `Modal` segue `UIViewController` you can manually add it in the `Interface Builder` :

[image]

And then you can add a `UIBarButton` to the `Navigation Bar`.

**But if you are still adamant on simply hiding the `Back` button, then use this method :**

Put this in the `viewDidLoad` method of your `UIViewController` class's implementation :

```
[self.viewController setHidesBackButton:YES animated:NO];
```

Comment: Right, I get that.  I tried a modal transfer, but then the nav bar totally disappears which I also don't want.  I just want the original Nav bar (which had an add button on the right side) without a new back button, if possible.

Comment: FYI - This will be a wrong approach if you want to `segue` from this `UIViewController` because it is a `Modal` segue.

Comment: Changing that setting in IB only changes the way IB renders it for you, it doesn't actually add the nav bar - that appears if and only if you are in a navigation controller and haven't hidden the bar.

Comment: ...and that is why you should scroll down to the bottom of my answer.